# Getting an "and" before the last block/element in \cite in BibLaTeX if elements are compressed

Tags: biblatex, citing, delimiters

Using BibLaTeX, I would like to create a `\textcite` command based on the numeric-comp style which instead of showing [1-3, 5] shows Refs. 1-3 and 5, and instead of showing [1-3, 5-7] gives Refs. 1-3 and 5-7.

I've been able to achieve the former, but not the latter with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

% Cite without square brackets - with Ref./Refs.
\NewBibliographyString{refname}
\NewBibliographyString{refsname}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    refname = {Ref\adddot},
    refsname = {Refs\adddot}
}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
{%
    \ifnum\thecitetotal=1
    \bibstring{refname}%
    \else%
    \bibstring{refsname}%
    \fi%
    \addnbspace%
    \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}%
    \renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\iflastcitekey{\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}{\addcomma\addspace}}%
}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:dump}\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A,
    title = {A Bla},
    author = {A Foo}
}

@book{B,
    title = {B Bla},
    author = {B Foo}
}

@book{C,
    title = {C Bla},
    author = {C Foo}
}

@book{D,
    title = {D Bla},
    author = {D Foo}
}

@book{E,
    title = {E Bla},
    author = {E Foo}
}

@book{F,
    title = {F Bla},
    author = {F Foo}
}

@book{G,
    title = {G Bla},
    author = {G Foo}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    
    Cite commands should stay like this (i.e. no and): \cite{A,B,C,E,F,G}

    These textcites work: \textcite{A,C,E,G} ; \textcite{A,B,C,E}
    
    This textcite misses the final and: \textcite{A,C,E,F,G}
    
    This textcite has two ands: \textcite{A,C,D,F}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output of the MWE:

[image: Output of the MWE]

I think the problem is that when citations are compressed, the last citekey is within a compressed interval and therefore no citation list delimiter is printed at all. Is there a test I could use to check which is the last delimiter actually printed, even if it is not before the last citekey? Also, note that in the last example there are somehow two 'ands', I think the problem again is that `\iflastcitekey` doesn't really work as expected.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you extend your code fragment into a small example that can be copy and pasted to compile please? Starting with your `\documentclass{}` and `\end{document}`

Comment: Added a full MWE now, and I've also discovered another problem with sometimes two 'ands' printed.

Comment: @JamesT - Here you are with the MWE. (Thanks CarLaTeX).

Comment: i can't reproduce your MWE, it no "and" between the citations. How are you compiling this?

Comment: @anis I'm compiling with pdfLaTeX, and BibLaTeX uses the (default) Biber backend. (This is all set up via MikTeX on Windows 11.)

Comment: See also the issue reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1273).